# UIWebview showing blank white screen after loading url

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Below is the code i have tried:

```
 HTMLBrowserViewController.h
 IBOutlet UIWebView * webControl;

 HTMLBrowserViewController.m

 webControl.scalesPageToFit = YES;

webControl.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

webControl.delegate = self;

NSURL *url1=[NSURL URLWithString:webUrl];

NSURLRequest *requestObject=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1 cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:15];    

[webControl loadRequest:requestObject];
```

Comment: check your url1 has output or not

Comment: as Anbu.Karthik suggested check the url in a normal browser or set stackoverflow.com as webUrl to test. Then check if your IBOutlet is connected and if so check if UIWebView delegate methods are being called

Comment: Sister show your url1.I will help you.

Comment: If you show your webUrl and url1,it will be very helpful.

Comment: Check your URL starts with http:// or not

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load an HTTP URL only, please check and enable the AllowArbitaryLoad In the App Transport Security Settings in the info.plist. You can refer to the following link.

[Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

If you are using the https URL, please make sure the URL is loading fine in the Safari and as well as in the Chrome browser responsive mode.

Sometimes, the website will load the response URL in iFrame. so please check that pass the correct URL.

Also, print the URL before you pass to the UIWebView, sometimes it should have space and as well as & so remove the same and pass it in the WebView.

```swift
serviceBookingUrl = [
    NSURLRequest requestWithURL : [
        NSURL URLWithString : [
            websiteURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString : @ "&amp;" withString : @ "&"
        ]
    ]
];
[PrimaryWebView loadRequest: serviceBookingUrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add NSAppTransportSecurity in your application .plist file**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

[Check this link transport Security has Blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Comment: @SanjanaBabhulgaonkar I think check your url it may url problem . what is your url?

Comment: Sister I am waiting for your response.please give webUrl and url1 for checking.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  NSString *encodedString=[urlString       stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"urlString %@",encodedString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedString];

    //URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Set delegete
    webView.delegate=self;

    //Load the request in the UIWebView.
    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```